# Dismissing a presented modal over a modal

Tags: ios, swift

I have a modal (modal 1) that presents another modal (modal 2), I want to dismiss the presented modal (modal 2) but when I call `dismiss` it dismiss both modal.

navigation controller -> presents modal A -> presents modal B

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let broadcastPrep = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "broadcast") as? BroadcastViewController
broadcastPrep?.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.navigationController?.present(broadcastPrep!, animated: true)
}
```

```swift
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "CommonViews", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"cutoffBroadcastWarning") as! BroadcastCutoffViewController
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
viewController.delegate = self
self.present(viewController, animated: true)
```

What happens when the sendButton is pressed, it dismiss both modal VC

```
class BroadcastCutoffViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    }

    @IBAction func sendButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I've done this before, so it *can* work. Any chance you could post enough code to duplicate the issue? That's the likely place to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You are presenting a view controller through navigationviewcontroller, all you need to do is

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.present(vc, animated: true,completion: nil)
}
```

so when you dismiss view controller it will dismiss only that specific view controller

Answer (score 0):

here's your answer, this works in Swift 5.1

```
@IBAction func sendButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.navigationController?.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

proof of concept

appdelegate

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?


  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let viewController = ViewController()
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)

    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
  }
}
```

viewcontroller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = .red

  }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let viewadf = UIViewController.init()
    viewadf.view.backgroundColor = .blue
    self.navigationController?.present(viewadf, animated: true, completion: {
      let viewadfs = UIViewController.init()
      viewadfs.view.backgroundColor = .yellow
      viewadf.present(viewadfs, animated: true, completion: {
        self.navigationController?.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

      })
    })
  }

}
```

this will dismiss the blue controller only, not the yellow controller

Comment: This works but it doesn't work the way I wanted it to be, the yellow container must be the one that must be dismissed first.